# AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'base.User' that has not been installed for custom auth backend

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm trying to customize auth backend while customized auth model but keep facing this error because i'm using `get_user_model()` function.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'base.User' that has not been installed

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'base.apps.BaseConfig',
     'core.apps.AccountsConfig',
     'system.apps.SystemConfig',
]
```

custom Backend:

```
class UserBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        usermodel = User
        try:
            usr = usermodel.objects.get(username=username)
            password_valid = usr.check_password(password)
            if usr and password_valid:
                return usr
            raise PermissionDenied
        except usermodel.DoesNotExist:
            return PermissionDenied
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        usermodel = User
        try:
            return usermodel.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except usermodel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

#### Edit:

settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.User'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'base.models.UserBackend',
)
```

`base.User` model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ManyToManyField('ImageFile', verbose_name="ProfilePicture", blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, default="")
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_official = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Note: UserBackend is on the end of file and `class User(AbstractUser)` is above it**

Comment: please show your `base.User` model

Comment: and what is your [settings auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth)  first (`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, `AUTH_USER_MODEL`)?

Comment: `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is above! @BearBrown

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace you are getting

Answer (score 2):

There was an import in `base.models` file, `from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend` which caused this error even when i removed custom `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.after i removed this import, everything works fine although i moved backend class from `base.models` to `backend` file in the `base` app (i think its not necessary, i just did it for more readable codes)

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem but doesn't explain how?

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the same. It took me over an hour to find out that you cannot have the CustomBackend(BaseBackend) and the CustomUser(AbstractUser) in the models.py of your app. This info is nowhere to be found in the official Django docs.

- Django Version: 3.1.2
- Python Version: 3.8.2

models.py of the app "Users":

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

auth.py (arbitrary name, living in the "Users" app):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend


class UserAuth(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username, password):
        pass

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        pass
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig'
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'users.auth.UserAuth'
]
```